# jQuery autocomplete: How to obtain HTML item's "id" attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

jQuery is new to me, thanks for bearing with me.

I have some text inputs in HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="NameTextID" id="fn.1">
<input type="text" class="NameTextID" id="ln.1">
<input type="text" class="EmailAddressTextID" id="ea.1">
```

Two inputs are of ***class*** `NameTextID` and one is of ***class*** `EmailAddressTextID`. Notice each ***id*** is unique.

I then would like to leverage jQuery's autocomplete function on any DOM item with a ***class*** from above.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $( ".NameTextID" ).autocomplete({
            source: recEngineNames,
            minLength: recMinCharCount,
            select: recEngine
        });
        $( ".EmailAddressTextID" ).autocomplete({
            source: recEngineEmails,
            minLength: recMinCharCount,
            select: recEngine,
        });
    });
});
```

Now, in the function recEngine:

```
var recEngine = function(event, ui) {
    var selected_value = ui.item.value
    var selected_id = ????
}
```

jQuery passes two parameters, how can I obtain the ***id*** if the ui item that activated the recEngine function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:-

```
var selected_id = this.id;
```

where `this` refers to the current element being referred to.

Comment: I'm given the response 'undefined'

Comment: ok, could you please do `console.log(ui.item)` and tell me what you are getting on any item selection? We mostly have id, label & value.

Comment: Object {label: "Some kind of text", value: "More text"}

Comment: ok, try `var selected_id = this.id`. Are you getting correct ids?

Comment: yes I am! I'll mark your answer correct as soon as you edit your answer with your above comment. Thank you

Comment: Done. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can acces it like this:
`ui.item.id`

Comment: I'm given the response 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

First thing you can use multi selectors by separating by a comma `','`.

Then to get the element where that fired the event you can use the key word `this`  or `event.target`.
To get its id you can use `$(event.target).attr('id')`

$(event.target).attr('id')

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $( ".NameTextID, .EmailAddressTextID" ).autocomplete({
            source: recEngineNames,
            minLength: recMinCharCount,
            select: recEngine
        });
    });
});

var recEngine = function(event, ui) {
    var selected_value = ui.item.value;
    var selected_id = $(event.target).attr('id');
}
```